# Is there a way to automatically link private repo's Github issues to the project board without access token?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Is there a way to automatically link Github issues to the project board without the access token?

I know that there is a way with access token like below.

https://github.com/alex-page/github-project-automation-plus

But, I'd like to link the private repository's issues when it's opened to the project board **without the access token because of security concerns.**

Is there any way to archive that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the only way to access your private repository by any service or library from outside is to use Personal Access Token.

You should not be concerned about the security of this solution as long as you keep your TOKEN in secret.